# Degree of C# support in SQL CLR user-defined function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, clr

This may be naive but I cannot get any confirmation of this: When I write a SQL function via the SQLCLR and as a C# SQL Server Project, can the SQL function include any method/class/namespace in the .NET BCL? Are there any restrictions on what the function can do? I have full control of the SQL Server and its hosting OS, so I can amend security settings at that level. I am more interested in the language support for C# in a SQLCLR user-defined function (SQL project).

My final deployment of code will be on SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2 (Enterprise Edition). As 2008 R2 would be a development on 2005 in terms of features and support, 2005 is my common denominator, hence I am interested in answers on 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not.  You can't use classes that have a [HostProtection] attribute that marks the class as unsafe.  Details are in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403276%28SQL.90%29.aspx), it includes lists of classes that are off limits.

The classic example of such a class is TimeZoneInfo, it loads an unmanaged DLL that won't be unloaded if there's a query abort.

```
[HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, MayLeakOnAbort=true)]
public sealed class TimeZoneInfo : IEquatable<TimeZoneInfo>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
{
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=VS.80).aspx is a good overview link as well.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET version depends on the SQL Server version:

- 2005 = .NET v2.0
- 2008/R2 = .NET v3.5

It's not full access to .NET - restrictions are based around the external_access parameter.  See this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx

Comment: unrelated, yet interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63007/omg-ponies-on-google